# Calling an EJB3 from local tomee

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, apache-tomee

I've spent most of my day on something that supposedly is very simple on EJB 3 in `Tomee`.

I have a `Test.jar` in the apps folder, and in it, there is a stateless bean with a method called `testMethod()`.

Bean: `TestBean.java`

Remote Interface: `Test.java`

In web application `TestClient.java`:

```
public String testMethod(){
   try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        Test test = (Test) ctx.lookup("Test");
        test.testMethod();
        //System.out.println("Output from JavaClient");
    } catch (NamingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and a JSP, which calls the `TestClient` class for execution.

I get the following error: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [Test] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [Test]`.

I have tried TestBean/remote in the context object with similar results.

Both the jar and the war are running in the same `tomee` container. If somebody can shed some light on what I am doing wrong, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the correct jndi name is in the logs (look for "Jndi(").

will likely be java:global//TestBean!Test or something like that